# installing objective c compiler

Tags: objective-c, ubuntu, gnu

i wanted to install objective c compiler for ubuntu.
this site was used to install GNUstep on ubuntu.
http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Installing_and_Using_GNUstep_and_Objective-C_on_Linux
then commands were written in following order in terminal-

---

```
sudo apt-get install gnustep  
sudo apt-get install gnustep-devel
```

then,i wrote my sample code and saved it as hello.m

---

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    NSLog (@"hello world");
    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

then,i typed in terminal

---

```
. /usr/share/GNUstep/Makefiles/GNUstep.
```

---

```
gcc `gnustep-config --objc-flags` -lgnustep-base hello.m -o hello
```

then,an error message appeared that

---

```
gcc: gnustep-config --objc-flags: No such file or directory
hello.m:1:23: fatal error: Foundation.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

then,i wrote

---

```
sudo apt-get install gobjc
```

then,terminal showed

---

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
gobjc is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 205 not upgraded.
```

then,i again compiled but it showed again the same error.

---

```
hp@ubuntu:~$ gcc 'gnustep-config --objc-flags' -lgnustep-base hello.m -o hello
gcc: gnustep-config --objc-flags: No such file or directory
hello.m:1:23: fatal error: Foundation.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

so,need some help..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try running:

```
gnustep-config --objc-flags
```

on its own to check if it returns error or appropriate gcc flags, etc.

Also, try finding the location for the include dir and add it explicitly with -Idir option to gcc

Comment: @sagacious The flag you are looking for is probably a `-I<path/to/foundatin/headers>` or equivalent that lets the compiler find `Foundation.h`

Comment: @JeremyP Yes, thats what I meant (saw your comment after my edit :)

Comment: @ManishJhawar yeah.got it.i was unable to find path to fondation.h.thanks